# generate a host list from ansible ini file

Tags: ansible

It is not possible to read this file with the [ini](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/ini.html#ini-read-data-from-a-ini-file) plugin.

```
$ cat hosts
[webservers]
www[01:50].example.com
```

The play

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_ini:
        - '.* section=webservers file=hosts re=True'
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=11].example.com) => {
    "msg": "11].example.com"
}
```

Is it possible to generate a host list like this?

```
[webservers]
www01.example.com
www02.example.com
www03.example.com
www04.example.com
www05.example.com
www06.example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Is it possible to generate a host list like ...?"*

A: Yes. Use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html#template-template-a-file-out-to-a-remote-server). For example

```
$ cat hosts
[webservers]
www[01:50].example.com

$ cat play.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_group: webservers
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: hosts-template.j2
        dest: /etc/ansible/hosts-webservers

$ cat hosts-template.j2 
[{{ my_group }}]
{% for my_host in groups[my_group] %}
{{ my_host }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Notes

- Ranges in the [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#working-with-inventory) will be expanded.
- If your ansible `hosts` inventory file is in a non standard location (i.e. not in `/etc/ansible/hosts`), you will have to load it when launching your playbook: `ansible-playbook -i /path/to/inventory/hosts play.yml`